# Set Properties and create events for a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a web user control in asp.net using C# in which i can select a date from a calendar and display it in a textbox. when i select a date from the calender it has to be displayed in the textbox. 
now i need to set my own properties by which i can select datetime patterns in cs codefile. for example

```
usercontrol1.dd-mm-yyyy.
```

this is one example. now i want all the datetime patterns of "en-us". when i use that usercontrol in another page i want to set any of the properties(datetime patterns) to that control. please help me!!!

i tried this coding but no use... plz review it and give me solution

public partial class DateControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

```
    string dateformat;

    public string Dateformat
    {
      get { return dateformat;}

        set { dateformat = value; }

    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {  
        PageLoad();
        lnlbtnChangeDate.Visible = false;
        ddlDateFormat.Visible = false;
        Calendar.Visible = false;
        }
        lblError.Visible = false;

    }
    public void PageLoad()
    {


        if (txtBoxDate.Text != "")
        {
            Calendar.Visible = false;
        }
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-fr");
        string[] format = ci.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
        foreach (string i in format)
        {
            ddlDateFormat.Items.Add(i);
        }

   }




    protected void lnkbtnPickDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar.Visible = true;
        lnlbtnChangeDate.Visible = true;
        ddlDateFormat.Visible = false;

     }



    public void Calendar_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBoxDate.Text = Calendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

    }

    protected void ddlDateFormat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtBoxDate.Text = Calendar.SelectedDate.ToString(ddlDateFormat.SelectedValue.ToString());   
    }


    protected void lnlbtnChangeDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar.Visible = false;
        if (txtBoxDate.Text == "")
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Visible = false;
            lnlbtnChangeDate.Visible = true;
            ddlDateFormat.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void lnkbtnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBoxDate.Text = "";
        Calendar.Visible = false;
        lnlbtnChangeDate.Visible = false;
        ddlDateFormat.Visible = false;
        lblError.Visible = false;
    }
```

i said that i want set properties for my user control and create events for that.... plz help me

Comment: I feel that you're asking something that many people can answer, but I'm afraid that it's not very clear what you wrote. You may try to clarify your question a little more.

Comment: thankx but i dont know to explain more than this can u please tell where its tuck

Comment: i had change my question. thankx for the review mr.claudio

Comment: It's still not clear what you're after. Are you looking for a way to get all datetime patterns for a specific local? Are you wondering how to pass state between two user controls? What is "another form", another page entirely, another control in the same aspx page? Also, what have you tried, what have you searched for, what haven't worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get it right at the question is not very clear, but anyway :

You could just create Properties for you user controls, and assign Enums to them

```
 public enum My_UserControl_DateFormats
    {
        YYYYMMDD = 1,
        YYYYMMDDHH = 2,
        YYYYMMDDHHmmSS = 3
    }
```

And in the setter code of your properties handle the logic to assign the Date Format (For Example) according to the enum value (using switch/case)

It's one among many possibilities.

Comment: i added my coding please review it and plz help me